# How do you print the contents of a glib GString to stdout?

Tags: glib

I am new to glib and its idioms.  I used a `GString` to accumulate a buffer from the download of a URL.  Now I want to print that buffer to stdout.
Right now I'm using code like

```
int len = catalogBuffer->len;
gchar *cat = g_string_free(catalogBuffer, FALSE);
catalogBuffer=0;
write(1, cat, len);  // this might not do everything if the OS returns a partial write
g_free(cat);
```

but it just seems clumsy.  Is there a better idiom to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The string returned from `g_string_free()` is 0-terminated, so you can do this:

```
char *cat = g_string_free(catalogBuffer, FALSE);
g_print("%s\n", cat);
g_free(cat);
```

Comment: That only works if the document I am downloading does not have any NULs in it.

Comment: Then it's a bad idea to print it to stdout with `write()`, isn't it?

Comment: `perl -e 'print("bacon\0eggs\n")' ` seems to work like I expect, so I am not afraid of writing NULs to stdout.

Comment: I thought you meant arbitrary binary data. If the zeroes are controlled, then you can do it; but it's really a niche use case, so there's no function especially for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the nul-terminated string directly out of the `GString`:

```
const char *cat = catalogBuffer->str;
g_print ("%s\n", cat);
…
g_string_free (catalogBuffer, TRUE);
```

Comment: That only works if the document I am downloading does not have any NULs in it.

Comment: Yes, but if you’re doing that, you shouldn’t be using a `GString`. `GString` is for UTF-8 data with no embedded nuls. Look at using a `GInputStream` or `GBytes`.